# Removing duplicate groups in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

I have a 'Distribution' table with two columns and these values:

**Elements**          | **Group**

p01,p02,p03,p04  |  **F**
p01,p02,p03  |  **A**
p01,p03,p04  |  **C**
p01,p03,p06  |  **E**
p01,p05  |  **G**
p02,p03  |  **D**
p07,p08  |  **I**
p08,p09  |  **J**
p06  |  **H**
p10  |  **L**

I would like to remove the duplicate groups and only get in the final sqlite query the "non-redundant" groups. Would it be possible to do it from the sqlite itself?

The result should be this:

**Elements**          | **Group**

p01,p02,p03,p04  |  **F**
p01,p03,p06  |  **E**
p01,p05  |  **G**
p07,p08  |  **I**
p08,p09  |  **J**
p10  |  **L**

Do you have any idea how I could do it, please?.

Thank you very much.
Wardiam

Comment: There are no duplicate groups in the data you've shown; all have different names and elements.

Comment: For example, the elements p01,p02,p03 into group A are contained into group F or elements p02,p03 into group D are also contained into group F. I want to remove these redundant groups.

Comment: First, split these lists into rows in a separate table.

Comment: CL, could you explain more in details how to split the lists, please? Could I use recursive common table expression?

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be in some other language.